# AWS IoT : How to update multiple thing shadows in one API call

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-iot

I am trying to update multiple thing shadows in one call.

I am using the API -  `UpdateThingShadow` (using AWS Lambda, AWS API gateway , GO SDK)

Since there are a lot of thing shadows, to be updated, I need to call this API sequentially. This results into timeout error.

As per the documentation of `UpdateThingShadow`, we can only pass one Thing name as the parameter.

Is there any way, I can update multiple thing shadows simultaneously?

Or is there any Async version of the `UpdateThingShadow` API ?

Answer (score 0):

there isn't a way to update multiple shadows at the same time. But there is an asynciotclient, instead of the iot client, where you can update the shadows in multiple calls.